# How do I display male or female based on certain conditions in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to rails and currently working on a dating application as a portfolio project. However, on my home page, I want to be able to display/render Male or Female data based on the gender of the `current_user`. That is if the logged-in user is a male, he will only be able to view people of the opposite gender since it's a dating application.

I am using Devise gem and included a custom field called `gender`. Please, someone should help me with how to do this.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user = current_user
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
```

User Table

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.text "short_bio"
    t.string "gender"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string "unconfirmed_email"
    t.integer "like"
    t.string "image_url"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

User Model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image
  has_many_attached :pictures

  has_many :messages
  has_many :likes
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :trackable

  # validates :short_bio, presence: true, length: {maximum: 500}
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, length: {minimum: 5, maximum: 50}
  

end
```

Comment: What does your `User` model look like and how did you define the `gender` attribute?
Btw. users _"will only be able to view people of the opposite gender since it's a dating application"_ excluded quite some user groups. I suggest asking the user about their _gender identity_ and the _preferred genders_ they are looking for with their potential partners.

Comment: @spickermann Thank you for your response. I have updated my question to include the model and database table for the user.

Comment: FYI, "Male" and "Female" are sexes, not genders. That field name should be `sex` not `gender`. Or if you really are talking about gender, then the terms are "Masculine" and "Feminine".

Comment: Also, what dating app restricts the user to the opposite sex or gender? That should be a user setting, not hard-coded.

Comment: @BenFenner quite a few that cater to religious groups. See the 2016 lawsuit against ChristianMingle for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only load users with the opposite gender than the current user like this:

```
@users = User.where.not(gender: current_user.gender)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need in the model two columns. It is just example as idea

You can use gender (it's not binary) instead of sex

You can use other data type of course

```
t.integer :sex
t.integer :look_for_sex
```

And for example:

0 -- female, 1 -- male

And then

```
User.where(sex: current_user.look_for_sex, look_for_sex: current_user.sex)
```

will return only users that current user want to date

Comment: Thank you. I didn't have to refactor my code but included the code ```@users = current_user == 'Male' ? User.where(gender: 'Male') : User.where(gender: 'Female')``` and that fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score -4):

Thank you for all that responded. I didn't have to refactor my code but just added the code below and that fixed my problem:

```
@users = current_user == 'Male' ? User.where(gender: 'Male') : User.where(gender: 'Female')
```

In this case, if the current user is a 'Male', he will only have access to 'Female' and vice versa.

Comment: IMHO this will not work because `current_user == 'Male'` will always be `false`. Assuming that `current_user` returns an instance of `User` and a `User` will never be equal to the string `'Male'`.

Comment: @spickermann It's working for me because my current is not false. What I did was to include the gender field on the Signup form; meaning, that as soon as a user signs up, we have access to the gender of the ```current_user```. With this, I am using it to check and render to the home page. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: This ternary is backwards. The way it reads right now it will collect all of the male users into `@users` if `current_user` is "Male" which doesn't sound like what you wanted.

Comment: @spickermann well if you really wanted to you could redefine the `==` method for maximum wonkyness. `class User; def ==(other); other.is_a?(String) ? self.gender == other : super; end; end`.